# Exponential Hindman's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, logic, exponentiation

I'm not familiar with the combinatorial proof of Hindman's theorem, but the proof using ultrafilters is quite slick and essentially only relies on the associativity of addition. As such, it also automatically gives the *multiplicative* version of Hindman's theorem: that for every $F:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{1,...,k\}$ there is an infinite $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that $F$ is homogeneous on the set of products of distinct elements of $A$.

My question is whether the *exponential* analogue of Hindman's theorem is true:

> Is it the case that, for every $F:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{1,...,k\}$, there is an infinite $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\mathsf{FinExp}(A):=\{x_1^{x_2^{.^{.^{.^{x_k}}}}}: x_1,...,x_k\in A\mbox{ distinct}\}$$ is $F$-homogeneous?

Certainly the ultrafilter-based proof breaks down: we can define a version of exponentiation in $\beta\mathbb{N}$, but it isn't a semigroup so we don't get idempotents. (EDIT: And I don't even see how to prove that, for every $F:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$, there are $a<b$ such that $\{a,b,a^b,b^a\}$ is $F$-homogeneous.) On the other hand, I don't see how to construct a counterexample (and the numbers get sufficiently big sufficiently quickly that experimentation hasn't been much help either).

Comment: You are asking for a seemingly very strong result. Do you know that some weaker statement holds, e.g., given $F:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$, do there exist $x,y\gt1$, $x\ne y$, with $F(x)=F(y)=F(x^y)=F(y^x)$? If so is that obvious or clever or a long brute-force calculation?

Comment: @bof I'm expecting a negative answer, so I asked the version I thought would be easiest to kill. But you're right: if it happens to be true, it's likely extremely hard to prove, so I should also probably ask about the weakest positive version.

Comment: @bof I just found Sisto's paper [*Exponential triples*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.3494.pdf); at a glance I don't think this answers my question, but it may be useful.

Comment: Di Nasso-Ragosta gave an ultrafilters proof of Sisto's result (https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.11764) and have an unpublished preprint proving that for every finite colouring of $\Bbb N$ you can find an infinite sequence $(a_i)$ such that $FA(a_i)$ (finite exponentiations of elements in the sequence) is monochromatic. It should be available soon. Note that some care is needed in defining $FA$ of a set since exponentiation is not even associative